# How to parse multiple single xml elements in .Net C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I'm trying to deserialise some xml that contains multiple single xml elements in .Net C#, like so:

```
<Root>
 <Status>OK</Status>
 <Person>
  <Name>Element 1</Name>
 </Person>
 <Person>
  <Name>Element 2</Name>
 </Person>
</Root>
```

The Person nodes are not in a `<Persons></Persons>`, therefore I cannot use the `[XmlArray]` attribute.

Does anyone know to do that, without having to use the XPath with XDocument.

Thanks

Comment: Make use of Linq to XML you can easily do your work......... have look to this to learn it : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoXML.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using .Net 3.5 or above, use Linq-to-XML:

```
string xml = "<root>...</root>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // Use .Load() if loading from a file
String status = doc.Root.Element("status").Value;
IEnumerable<string> personNames = doc.Root.Descendants("person").Select(x => x.Element("name").Value);
```