# Deserializing poorly structured XML without linq C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, serialization

I have an external xml feed that is pretty poorly structured so Im not sure how to deserialize it directly.

I can not use System.IO.Linq in my assembly so the only solution I know of cant be used.

Example of this xml is

```
<body>
    <route>
        <stop tag="Info I need to get"/>
        <stop tag="Info I need to get"/>
        <path>
            <point tag="info I need to get"/>
            <point tag="info I need to get"/>
            <point tag="info I need to get"/>
        </path>
        <path>
            <point tag="info I need to get"/>
        </path>
        <path>
            <point tag="info I need to get"/>
            <point tag="info I need to get"/>
        </path>
    </route>
</body>
```

if I could somehow parse all the path points into an array I can get the data inside the tags easily.

the linq solution I was refering to is mentioned at [How to parse multiple single xml elements in .Net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166992/how-to-parse-multiple-single-xml-elements-in-net-c-sharp)

Comment: You could simply read the XML and parse it the old fashion way without using any Serialization process.

Comment: Are you talking about through a series of string expressions? Id rather leave that as the last resort if possible lol.

Comment: What? No... I meant getting a XMLDocument stream and navigating the nodes manually.

Comment: ...you said old fashioned haha

Comment: Alright... Regular expression your ass out of it. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **XPath** to select all nodes having `tag` attribute

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("myfile.xml");

foreach (XmlElement node in doc.SelectNodes("//*[@tag]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name + ": " + node.GetAttribute("tag"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend using array list since I would guess you do not now exact number of nodes

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("sample.xml");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("point"); // You can also use XPath here
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   list.Add(node);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)?

You might need to learn some XPath to be able to navigate it well, but this should do the trick.

You could also just do something simple like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("myfile.xml");
foreach(XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("point"))
{
    var valueYouWant = node.Attributes["tag"].Value;
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XmlSerializer :

Here is a good example: [Simple XmlSerializer example](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&sqi=2&ved=0CEcQFjAD&url=http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm&ei=Z3SmUNWGIIuc9QS_zoHQCg&usg=AFQjCNHYn9JlJugrHHc3ZynSQuzVnqLQ9A&sig2=B0MECiVUDY-eogdBGwHsKQ)

This would allow you to serialize the object for storage.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use the xml reader [XML Reader MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) you can just look for elements of type **path** and load the attribute data using something similar to [Reading Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by2bd43b.aspx)